# Thinkpad X201 Touchscreen Missing on Resume

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, multi-touch, touchscreen, wacom

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Thinkpad X201 with a Wacom Touchscreen. The touchscreen seems to work fine, but upon resume after suspending, the touchscreen does not work. It actually doesn't even show up when I run:

> xsetwacom --list

I initially had Ubuntu 13.04 on this laptop but these issues only came into existence once I upgraded to the latest release. The only way I seem to be able to get the touchscreen working again is if I reboot or run:

> sudo lightdm restart

Is there some way I can force a reload of the necessary components to use the touchscreen upon resume?

SideNote: *One other annoying thing which doesn't work after upgrading is the rotate button at the bottom of the screen.*

Answer (score 4):

I use saucy with X201 tablet. This command brings the touchscreen back to life for me:

```
sudo inputattach --daemon -w8001 /dev/ttyS4
```

Comment: user107042, +1, but you should add, if possible, some references or explications (why this command works, from where you got it, etc.). Like it is now is a kind of magic incantation that does not help understanding the problem. And maybe for other users it is important to be able to tune it... (for example, is `/dev/ttyS4` fixed? I doubt it...)